# Error with SQL string: "Error while connecting to PostgreSQL operator does not exist: date = integer"

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a Python(3) script that is supposed to run each morning. In it, I call some SQL. However I'm getting an error message:

> Error while connecting to PostgreSQL  operator does not exist: date = integer

The SQL is based on the concatenation of a string:

```
ecom_dashboard_query = """
with 
days_data as (
select 
    s.date,
    s.user_type,
    s.channel_grouping,
    s.device_category,
    sum(s.sessions) as sessions,
    count(distinct s.dimension2) as daily_users,
    sum(s.transactions) as transactions,
    sum(s.transaction_revenue) as revenue
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions s
where date = """ + run.start_date + """
group by 1,2,3,4
)

insert into flagship_reporting.ecom_dashboard
select *
from days_data;
"""
```

Here is the full error:

```
09:31:25  Error while connecting to PostgreSQL  operator does not exist: date = integer
09:31:25  LINE 14: where date = 2020-01-19
09:31:25                      ^
09:31:25  HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried wrapping `run.start_date` within str like so: `str(run.start_date)` but I received the same error message.

I suspect it may be to do with the way I concatenate the SQL query string, but I am not sure.

The query runs fine in SQL directly with a hard coded date and no concatenation:

```
where date = '2020-01-19'
```

How can I get the query string to work correctly?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation, that's what caused the problem. No amount of quoting or escaping can fix the fundamental problems. Use parameters instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more better to pass query params to `cursor.execute` method. From [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)

> Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

So instead of string concatenation pass `run.start_date` as second argument of `cursor.execute`.

In your query instead of concatenation use `%s`:

```
where date = %s
group by 1,2,3,4
```

In your python code add second argument to `execute` method:

```
cur.execute(ecom_dashboard_query , (run.start_date,))
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me this! Just a follow up. You have a comma after run.start_date... is that a typo? Also, why is run.start_date in parenthesis? Would it be OK to also do `cur.execute(ecom_dashboard_query , run.start_date)`? Just curious

Comment: @DougFir no, it not a typo, `execute` expecting sequence or mapping so if we need to provide one paramether we need to convert it to sequence(tuple) that's what this comma doing. You can read about this method here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute

Answer (score 1):

Your sentece is wrong:

where date = """ + run.start_date + """

try to compare a date and a string and this is not posible, you need to convert "run.start_date" to datetime and compare simply:

```
date_format = datetime.strptime(your_date_string, '%y-%m-%d')
```

and with this date converted to datetime do:

```
where date = date_format
```

Final code:

```
date_format = datetime.strptime(your_date_string, '%y-%m-%d')
ecom_dashboard_query = """
with 
days_data as (
select 
    s.date,
    s.user_type,
    s.channel_grouping,
    s.device_category,
    sum(s.sessions) as sessions,
    count(distinct s.dimension2) as daily_users,
    sum(s.transactions) as transactions,
    sum(s.transaction_revenue) as revenue
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions s
where date = {}
group by 1,2,3,4
)

insert into flagship_reporting.ecom_dashboard
select *
from days_data;
""".format(date_format)
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my first issue with understanding how to compare string and dates. I think I'm leaning to neverwalkerloners solution though since there are some issues with concatenating SQL strings more generally I wasn't aware off

Comment: "format" is the best way to set vars to a query, you can put a variable or whatever you want followed by ",". So, is your query running yet?

Comment: It's part of a pipeline that will run in an hour... will find out soon!